# How to avoid displaying a storage provider sync root in Windows File Manager root

Tags: filter, uwp, filesystems, cloud, virtualfilesystem

I am creating a file system using a storage provider and Windows Cloud Files API. I want to avoid displaying a sync root in Windows File Manager:

[image]

Here the code that I use to register sync root:

```
        string path = "C:\\Users\\User1\\DAV\\";
        StorageProviderSyncRootInfo storageInfo = new StorageProviderSyncRootInfo();
        storageInfo.Path = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
        storageInfo.Id = syncRootId;
        storageInfo.DisplayNameResource = "WebDAV Drive";
        storageInfo.IconResource = "C:\\Drive.ico";
        storageInfo.Version = "1.0"
        storageInfo.RecycleBinUri = new Uri("https://userfilesystem.com/recyclebin");
        storageInfo.Context = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(path, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        storageInfo.HydrationPolicy = StorageProviderHydrationPolicy.Progressive;
        storageInfo.HydrationPolicyModifier = StorageProviderHydrationPolicyModifier.AutoDehydrationAllowed | StorageProviderHydrationPolicyModifier.ValidationRequired;

        storageInfo.PopulationPolicy = StorageProviderPopulationPolicy.Full;

        storageInfo.InSyncPolicy =
            StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.FileCreationTime    | StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.DirectoryCreationTime |
            StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.FileLastWriteTime   | StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.DirectoryLastWriteTime |
            StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.FileHiddenAttribute | StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.DirectoryHiddenAttribute |
            StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.FileSystemAttribute | StorageProviderInSyncPolicy.DirectorySystemAttribute;
        
        StorageProviderSyncRootManager.Register(storageInfo);
```

A complete code could be found in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ITHit/UserFileSystemSamples/blob/master/Windows/Common/Core/Registrar.cs#L212-L256).

How do I make my file system not show up at the root level in Windows File Manager?

Comment: Hello, i got almost same task, can i ask couple of questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Integrate a Cloud Storage Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage#step-3-add-your-extension-to-the-navigation-pane-and-make-it-visible) article  you can edit your Sync Root registration info and modify `HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{<GUID>}\ System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` value to be 0. This will hide your sync root folder from explorer tree. User will still be able to see it if he turns on "Show all folders" option.

To find you SyncRoot CLSID you need to open sync root registration manager and locate your registration entry: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager\<your sync root>\ NamespaceCLSID`