# How do I mount a cloud storage provider as a drive?

Tags: cloud-storage, virtualfilesystem, fileprovider, virtual-drive

I am creating a custom cloud storage provider for Windows, based on [this repo](https://github.com/ITHit/UserFileSystemSamples/tree/master/VirtualFileSystem). I have removed the root node in the Windows file manager as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931870/how-to-avoid-displaying-a-storage-provider-sync-root-in-windows-file-manager-roo/66066726#66066726). Now I need to mount it as a drive.

How do I display my custom cloud storage provider as a drive?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a little late but have a look at the answers - they may help you decide what approach to take as there's no native way to mount GCP buckets (or other storage) in Windows as a file system.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334837/12257250) as it presents some of the tools (free & proprietary) and workarounds you can use (such as mounting filesystem in Linux and sharing it as a Samba/NFS with windows):