# How to use GCP bucket data on windows file system

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fuse

I want to access GCP bucket data on windows 10 as file system.

GCP provide FUSE for mac and Linux, Is there any way to mount GCP bucket with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordingly to the documentation [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse):

> Cloud Storage FUSE is an open source FUSE adapter that allows you to mount Cloud Storage buckets as file systems on Linux or macOS systems.

As a result, there is no easy way of using it on the Windows systems.

**There are a few possible ways to solve it**:

1. [Rclone](https://rclone.org/)

   > Rclone is a command line program to manage files on cloud storage. It is a feature rich alternative to cloud vendors' web storage interfaces. Over 40 cloud storage products support rclone including S3 object stores, business & consumer file storage services, as well as standard transfer protocols.

   - Install Rclone and [WinFsp](http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/). Remember to add Rclone location to your `PATH`.
   - Follow the [instructions](https://rclone.org/googlecloudstorage/) to set up your remote GCP bucket. If your GCP bucket use [Uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access), remember to set the `--gcs-bucket-policy-only` option to true when configuring Rclone remote drive.
   - [Mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) the remote GCP bucket as a local disk

     ```
     rclone mount remote:path/to/files X:
     ```

     where `X:` is an unused drive letter.
2. [GcsFuse-Win](https://github.com/weswu8/gcsfuse-win):

   > GcsFuse-Win is a distributed FUSE based file system backed by Google cloud storage service. It is the first open source native version of gcs fuse on windows.It allows you to mount the buckets/folders in the storage account as a the local folder/driver on Windows system. It support the cluster mode. you can mount the blob container (or part of it) across multiple windows nodes.
3. [CloudBerry Drive](https://www.msp360.com/drive.aspx) (proprietary software):

   > Mount cloud storage as a network drive to your Windows workstation or Windows Server
4. Mount bucket with FUSE into a Linux instance and share it via network Samba/NFS.

Answer (score 2):

Another three tools that may be usefull here are:

[NetDrive](https://www.netdrive.net/) - this is a paid software (~50USD per lifetime licence). You can try it out for free however (7 days trial) and it will actually allow you to mount whatever GCP storage you have as a filesystem in Windows.

[Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/) - has very similar abilities and also allows mounting GCP storage in Windows - it's sligtly cheaper ~40USD for one user but it's valid for a specific major version.

[CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/) - is the free (or libre as the official page states) version of the Mountain Duck - it doesn't allow mounting resources as a filesystem but it still let you access any cloud storage via it's interface simple & intuitive).